# error: invalid conversion from 'int*' to 'int'

Tags: c++

I have the following function, and I cannot understand what is wrong with it. I am a first-timer, so please be as simplistic as you can.

I get the error at the 3rd single loop, where I try to assign some values to an array, sizes matching, and I don't know how to fix it.

```
int Planet::locateClosestDanger(int x,int y){
int n=0;
for (int i=0;i<getZones()->size();i++){ // evaluate the size of the array
    if (getZones()->at(i)->getAccessDanger()>0.5){
        n++;
    }
}
int m=0;
int dangerAtX[n];
int dangerAtY[n];
for (int i=0;i<getZones()->size();i++){ // assign values to arrays for the locations of the objects
    if (getZones()->at(i)->getAccessDanger()>=0.6){
        dangerAtX[m]=getZones()->at(i)->getPosZoneX();
        dangerAtY[m]=getZones()->at(i)->getPosZoneY();
        m++;
    }
}
float r[n];
for (int i=0;i<n;i  // compute all euclidean distances and assign values to array
    r[i]=BOO::eudi(x,y,dangerAtX,dangerAtY);    // here I get the error
}
int temp;
int q=r;
for (int i=0;i<n;i++){  // Bubblesort, smallest euclidean distance goes to r[0]
    for (int j=0;j<n-1;j++){
        if (r[j]>r[j+1]){
            temp=r[j];
            r[j]=r[j+1];
            r[j+1]=temp;
        }
    }
}
int index;
for (int i=0;i<n;i++){  // find index on array, coordinates of r[0]
    if (q[i]=r[0]){
        index=i;
    }
}
return dangerAtX[index], dangerAtY[index]; // return the coordinates
```

}

```
namespace BOO{
float eudi(int x,int y,int X,int Y){
    return sqrt((float)pow(abs(x-X),2)+(float)pow(abs(y-Y),2));
}
```

}

Comment: Can you show the `BOO::eudi` function, or at least its declaration?

Comment: Provide a [short, self-contained, correct example](http://sscce.org/). Where is `Boo::eudi()` defined? If the error is in the third `for` loop, why do you show us the first, second, fourth  and fifth `for`-loop?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo, and [we close all typo questions](meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/167342/close-all-the-typo-questions).


Comment: float eudi(int x,int y,int X,int Y){
        return sqrt((float)pow(abs(x-X),2)+(float)pow(abs(y-Y),2));
    }

Comment: Don't add source code via comments. Edit your question instead.

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
for (int i=0;i<n;i  // compute all euclidean distances and assign values to array
    r[i]=BOO::eudi(x,y,dangerAtX,dangerAtY);    // here I get the error
}
```

is missing `) {`

Also

```
return dangerAtX[index], dangerAtY[index]; // return the coordinates
```

will not return an `x,y` coordinate. The return type of your function is `int` and the value of the `,` operator will evaluate to the last expression in the list, in your case `dangerAtY[index]`. Use `std::pair` to return a pair of values.

As per your comment the signature of `BOO::eudi` is `eudi(int x,int y,int X,int Y)` while you pass the `dangerAtX` and `dangerAtY` arrays as third and fourth parameter. `dangerAtX` and `dangerAtY` are if type `int *` while the method expects `int`. You probably meant to call `BOO::eudi(x,y,dangerAtX[i],dangerAtY[i])`.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i=0;i<n;i  // ...
```

Missing closing parenthesis, and opening bracket.

With the declaration

```
float eudi(int x,int y,int X,int Y)
```

you say that the function `eudi` takes four `int` arguments, but when you call the function you pass two arrays (which decays to pointers) as the last two parameters.

You probably meant to do

```
BOO::eudi(x,y,dangerAtX[n],dangerAtY[n]);
```

Notice the use of indexing of the arrays.

Comment: It's a typo. Even with the parenthesis I get the error.

Comment: @user2944391 Updated answer in response to your question comment

Comment: You are right. It's fixed. May I ask one more thing? How can I make a copy of the array? I try to use q=r, where r is the array, but I get an error again. Have you any suggestions?

Comment: @user2944391 Use [`memcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy): `memcpy(q, r, size_in_bytes)`

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown us the eudi method's declaration but I would bet that it is wrong.

Your array dangerAtX is defined thus:

`int dangerAtX[n];`

It is an array of `int`s, so the identifier `dangerAtX` has the type `int*`. What types do you have for the third and fourth parameters to eudi?

Comment: Definition of eudi:
float eudi(int x,int y,int X,int Y){
        return sqrt((float)pow(abs(x-X),2)+(float)pow(abs(y-Y),2));
    }

Comment: @user2944391 Yep, that's the problem. dangerAtX is an int*, but dangerAtX[0] will be an int. Change the dangerAtX in your call to `dangerAtX[i]`.

Comment: All the input arguments are int.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. It's fixed now.